# How to enable WCF Services on Windows 10 with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, wcf

Could someone help me enable WCF services on Windows 10? I tried commands listed below but only WCF-TCP-PortSharing45 was enabled.

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-Services45
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-HTTP-Activation45
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-TCP-Activation45
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-Pipe-Activation45
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-MSMQ-Activation45
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-TCP-PortSharing45
```

Windows features on my computer:

[image: My Windows features]

Comment: Show what output you get when run this comands, need more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where-Object {$_.State -like "Disabled" -and $_.FeatureName -like "*WCF*"} | % {Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $_.FeatureName -All}
```

This did it for me. The key being the -All flag: from [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/enable-windowsoptionalfeature?view=win10-ps):

> Enables all parent features of the specified feature. If a parent
>   feature is required for the specified feature to be enabled in the
>   image, All will enable the parent and all of its default dependencies.

This is where running your above commands failed for me as well with the error message that:

```
 "One or several parent features are disabled so current feature can not be enabled"
```

My answer uses a loop to grab every available WindowsOptionalFeature. Additionally, you could simply run your above commands with the -All parameter like so:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-Services45 -All
```

Comment: Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where-Object {$_.State -like "Disabled" -and $_.FeatureName -like "*WCF*"} | % {Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $_.FeatureName -All}

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. The code you provided worked beautifully.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it! If this worked for you please mark my answer as the correct solution.

Comment: How to get the list of dependencies if we use -All flag ?